# The method read(capture#2-of ?) in the type GenericDao<Order,capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Long)

Tags: java, generics

First time doing generics and I am a bit confused here.

I have the following:

```
public interface GenericDao<T, PK extends java.io.Serializable> {

    /**
     * Retrieve an object that was previously persisted to the database
     * using the reference id as primary key
     * 
     * @param id primary key
     * @return
     */
    public T read(PK id);
}


public class GenericDaoHibernateImpl<T, PK extends java.io.Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, PK>
{
    private Class<T> type;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public GenericDaoHibernateImpl(Class<T> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T read(final PK id)
    {
        return (T) getSession().get(type, id);
    }
}

  <bean id="orderDao" class="vsg.ecotrak.framework.dao.GenericDaoHibernateImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
      <value>vsg.ecotrak.common.order.domain.Order</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then my service class just calls up this.getOrderDao().read(pId) where pId is passed to the load method on the service class as a Long.

Comment: Do you have the code for OrderDao?

Comment: <bean id="orderDao" class="vsg.ecotrak.framework.dao.GenericDaoHibernateImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
      <value>vsg.ecotrak.common.order.domain.Order</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

Comment: You should retitle your question to something like "How do I get generics to work in a Spring context?" and then include the exception in your question text. This will make it easier for people to find later.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the Spring declaration of `orderDao`. The way you have written it, it will be interpreted by Spring as

```
new GenericDaoHibernateImpl(Order something)
```

whereas generics would require a signature like this (removing the unnecessary constructor argument).

```
new GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Order,Long>()
```

You can't directly infer generics from Spring due to type erasure at runtime, but you could create a new class

```
public class OrderDao extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Order,Long> { }
```

and reference it as it's own bean in Spring

```
<bean id="orderDao" class="vsg.ecotrak.framework.dao.OrderDao">
  <property name="sessionFactory"> <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

The generics are contained in the OrderDao which will behave as expected by only returning Orders based on Long PK.

Comment: thanks.  I was trying to avoid the need to create DAO objects all the time.  I ended up removing the PK from the generic and make use of Long data type directly.

Comment: @boyd4715 Glad I could help. As an aside, you may want to post up your solution so that others can benefit from it. There's no harm in accepting your own answer, too.